# Browserify execute a module code only once , on multiple require calls

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, browserify, commonjs

app.js

```
var MedicineManager = new Marionette.Application();

MedicineManager.addRegions({
    mainRegion: "#main-region"
});

MedicineManager.navigate = function (route, options) {
    options || (options = {});
    Backbone.history.navigate(route, options);
};

MedicineManager.getCurrentRoute = function () {
    return Backbone.history.fragment;
};

MedicineManager.on("start", function () {
    if (Backbone.history) {
        Backbone.history.start();
    }
});

$(function () {
    MedicineManager.start();
})

module.exports=MedicineManager;
```

I am trying to move my app from Marionette module pattern to Browserify.

I am calling `require('app')` in multiple files, and this causes the code in app.js to execute everytime a `require('app')` call is made.

Because of this I am getting error that `Backbone.history has already been started`.
The solution to this problem is that the code be called only once at initialization.

How do I solve it?

Comment: I honestly feel that I don't need the Application object at all when using a module pattern. Just get rid of it, have a `app.js` file that starts history and sets up the router. With Regions, Initializers and Application channel [deprecated](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.3.1/marionette.application.html) and an imminent v3.x release I personally feel it really doesn't provide much useful stuff when you have a module system as well.

Comment: will definitely try it

Comment: any suggestions to resources which can provide me headstart as to what you said would be appreciated

Comment: I can try to write up an answer with some scaffolding for the way I set up my last Marionette project but I can't make any promises since I'm a bit busy at the moment (which is why I commented instead of answering). There's nothing wrong with the suggestion in the accepted answer (and if you want polymorphic you can even check if you're on the server and use `global` instead of `window`).

Comment: can you provide a link to the project if possible

Comment: and thanks for your time

Comment: That's the problem, it's for a client and not open source so I can't really share the source. I'll try to get around to writing up an example but it would be by tuesday at the earliest.

Comment: no problem....anytime would be fine, as long as I can learn something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use `require` for instantiated objects. It can be used, but experience has shown that while the module export should be cached, there are many instances when it is not and an error is thrown. I have found that it's best to use `require` for static objects/methods.  The best approach to ensure singletons is to instantiate in your root method, and then pass the instance into modules that require it.

If you want to use `require` to refactor an existing code base, you can bind the instantiated object to a global object (like `window`) and then check in your initiation section for the instance of this object on that global object and return it instead.

```
module.exports = function () {
    if (!window.__medicineManager){
        var MedicineManager = new Marionette.Application();

        MedicineManager.addRegions({
            mainRegion: "#main-region"
        });

        MedicineManager.navigate = function (route, options) {
            options || (options = {});
            Backbone.history.navigate(route, options);
        };

        MedicineManager.getCurrentRoute = function () {
            return Backbone.history.fragment;
        };

        MedicineManager.on("start", function () {
            if (Backbone.history) {
                Backbone.history.start();
            }
        });

        MedicineManager.start();
        window.__medicineManager = MedicineManager;
    }
    return window.__medicineManager;
}()
```

---

### Update:

As an aside, it seems that Browerify specifically has this issue (more so than CommonJS or WebPack).  Perhaps moving to a different module system will resolve this issue for you.  Ultimately, the issue remains that instantiated modules are a bit of a misuse of the pattern.  While polluting the global scope isn't ideal, I think it's a step closer to the singleton pattern that you are wanting and will always work, regardless of a build tool's particular module caching method.

Comment: but isn't it a bad practice to pollute global namespace

Comment: It is in theory, especially if you want to run polymorphic code. However, if your goal is to launch working code in a timely manner without having to rewrite an entire library, then it becomes a question of lesser evils.

Comment: I think for time being, I would go with your solution